# Creating new file with special characters using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am using CSOM for creating new file. The file name contains specials characters.

The file name is **!@@#$#%$%^^&^&(())(_+{}}.rar** If I create file name as it is it gets fails or partially created

```
FileCreationInformation f_ObjInfo   =  new FileCreationInformation();
f_ObjInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream();
f_ObjInfo.Url           = f_Url+ "/"+"!@@#$#%$%^^&^&(())(_+{}}.rar"

f_DestFolder.Files.Add(f_ObjInfo);
f_DestFolder.Update();
f_CContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How can I handle special characters wile file creation?

> **Update**
>
> > I also tried with
> >
> > ```
> >  System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("!@@#$#%$%^^&^&(())(_+{}}.rar");
> > ```
> >
> > but not able to encode all characters properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try doing a search on our beloved SP SE:  [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=special+characters)

Comment: Wha did `UrlEncode` return?

Comment: It return !%40%40%23%24%23%25%24%25%5e%5e%26%5e%26(())(_%2b%7b%7d%7d.rar 
and after file creation it displays name as !@@#$%23%25$%25^^&^&(())(_+{}} which is not same as source

Answer (score 0):

To support # and % you should use new [ResourcePath API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api)

```
fileResourcePath = ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl(f_Url+ "/"+"!@@#$#%$%^^&^&(())(_+{}}.rar");
f_DestFolder.Files.AddUsingPath(fileResourcePath, new FileCollectionAddParameters(), new MemoryStream());
```